# Discrepancy between function printing and print function output in Python

Tags: python, printing, return

I have a (perhaps clumsy) function to find the largest prime factor of a number `n` (below).

```
def largest_prime_factor(n,factor=2):
    if n % factor == 0:
        if n == factor:
            return factor
        else:
            largest_prime_factor(n/factor,factor)
    else:
        largest_prime_factor(n,factor+1)

#Printing function output
print largest_prime_factor(600)
```

But when I try to print the function's returned output it simply says `None`. However, when I make the function print its output (below) it prints the correct answer (5). What am I doing wrong in the snippet above?

```
def largest_prime_factor(n,factor=2):
    if n % factor == 0:
        if n == factor:
            print factor #Printing, not returning
        else:
            largest_prime_factor(n/factor,factor)
    else:
        largest_prime_factor(n,factor+1)

#Calling the function
largest_prime_factor(600)
```

Comment: Hint: since you're using recursion - the `print` statement will only see the outer most return...

Comment: @JonClements do you ever sleep?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed some return calls :

```
def largest_prime_factor(n,factor=2):
    if n % factor == 0:
        if n == factor:
            return factor
        else:
            return largest_prime_factor(n/factor,factor)
    else:
        return largest_prime_factor(n,factor+1)
```